# Proof that $p(z)^2=a^2$ always has a nonreal solution.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, galois-theory, real-numbers

Let $p(z)$ be a nonconstant integer polynomial of degree $n$ such that $p(0)=0$ and let $a$ be a nonzero real number.

It seems that

$$p(z)^2=a^2$$

Always has a nonreal solution (in $z$) if $n>1.$

Or maybe it is only true if $n$ is even.

It is easy to prove for the special case of $n=2$ but I do not know how to handle it otherwise.

I got the idea ( from the proof of the special case $n=2$ ) that only the degree $n$ matters here and *not* the coefficients of $p(z)$.

I also wonder if the divisors of $n$ have a special meaning here.

Could the concept of complex conjugate be used here ?

I know ofcourse that an equivalent problem is :

$$(p(z)-a)(p(z)+a)=0$$

And one can then see the question as a problem about a system of 2 equations.
But it is not clear to me how that helps.

Despite not being able to find a proof in any book, I assume there are many proofs for this.

I think it is easy, but I can not see it.

A possible proof might be based upon the fact that the coefficients of a polynomial can be expressed by its zero's.

Comment: What if $p(z) = z^2 - 5$ and $a = 4$? The equation $p(z)^2 = a^2$ then has $4$ real solutions: $z = \pm 1$ and $z = \pm 3$.

Comment: See my important edit

Comment: This still breaks in degree $2$: for $p(z) = z(z - 2)$ and $a = \frac{1}{2}$, $p(z)^2 = a^2$ has 4 real roots: $z = 1 \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4\pm 2}$.

Comment: Im sorry, I made a mistake. Thanks @JanLadislavDussek
Not sure what to do now.